# Query match all tokens in field, not any

Tags: lucene

For a script I need to compare ad titles against a lucene index.
This index contains a couple of keywords and the action to take if the ad matches.

For example:

```
(keyword,action,new_category,optional)
"red volvo","recategorize","cars","red"
```

The idea is that I need to query the whole ad title against the keyword field. Both (query and index) are analyzed with my own analyzer which has stemming, lowercasing, etc.

The problem I'm having is with partial matches. For example:
"I am selling a red horse" is matching "red volvo".

If it were the other way around (the ads were indexed and I would need to query by the keyword) I could do:

```
q=+red +volvo
```

But that's not an option due to the huge amount of ads I need to process.

So, the concrete question, **is there a way to force all tokens in a field to be matched against the query?**
I could use a KeywordAnalyzer so the whole 'red volvo' is seen as one token, but I cannot analyze the whole ad title as a single keyword, because it won't match anything.

Comment: I'm not quite certain I understand this correctly.  You have a document field to search which contains, in it's entirety "red volvo", and when querying, you DO NOT wish to see a match with the query: "I am selling a red horse", but you DO want a match with the query: "I am selling a red horse who owns a blue volvo".  Is that right?

Comment: @femtoRgon preferably the two words should be one next to the other, but if that's not possible, I can live with both words appearing anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you do want to catch the phrase "red volvo" exactly, but never just "red" or "volvo", then I think you are on the right track with indexing it using the keyword analyzer.  But you want to search with a longer query than than the field your searching, which is sort of the reverse of the typical use case.

I hesitate to recommend it, but I think the right way to go about this query might be to use a different analyzer to query than the one you use to create the index.

If the phrases indexed are of a predictable size, say 2-5 words, then using a [ShingleFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleFilter.html) could produce the terms you need from a long query to search it as a Keyword.

Something like this:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new WhitespaceAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);
analyzer = new ShingleAnalyzerWrapper(analyzer, 1, 5); //wrapper that adds a ShingleFilter to the analyzer
QueryParser parser = new StandardQueryParser(analyzer);  
Query query = parser.parse(query, defaultField);
searcher.search(query, 10);
```

This will split only on whitespace, and then produce search terms of 1 to 5 tokens in length, so in the example:  "I am selling a red horse" is will produce the terms like "I", "am", "I am", "red horse", "I am selling", "am selling a red horse", etc.

I think a whitespace filter is probably the best choice for making this work with keywords, but if you run into whitespace characters it splits on other than spaces, or more than one space in a row, you may run into problems.

Comment: Each shingle will be treated as a single token right? (as it was a keyword, even with the space).

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Keep in mind, again, though, the query will be tokenized into words around whitespace, and then spaces will be reinserted by the ShingleFilter, thus the concerns I mentioned regarding inconsistent whitespace.  The KeywordAnalyzer doesn't tokenize at all, so nothing will be changed about it's whitespace (stuff like this is why you usually don't want to use different analyzers for query parsing and indexing).  It might be a good idea implement some normalization on indexing to ensure this won't be a problem.

Comment: I've actually done something different, but this seems like a good approach. I basically took the top matching document, did a split on whitespace and checked if all words were in the query. Since I have my own external analyzer I can get the tokens from the title and the matching keyword and then compare.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you could use Lucene's [MemoryIndex](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/memory/index.html): "this class targets fulltext search of huge numbers of queries over comparatively small transient realtime data (prospective search)"

Comment: any example or comment why? I couldn't find anything that specifies that MemoryIndex can do the type of query that I want.

Comment: I don't believe this addresses the issue.  MemoryIndex (small, usually temporary) creates an index in RAM, rather than storing on disk.  It doesn't change anything about how it's queried.

Comment: @femtoRgon indeed. I was of course using a RAMDirectory already, which I think works similarly.

Comment: Indeed.  Looks like MemoryIndex incorporates some very significant added efficiences compared to RAMDirectory, but they appear to work pretty similarly.

Comment: You said "If it were the other way around ... But that's not an option due to the huge amount of ads" - as MemoryIndex is 10 to 100 times faster than RAMDirectory according to the javadoc, I thought this might actually be an option.